# Map using ggplot, facet by location

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data like this:

```
    LocationData<-structure(list(Address = c("London, UK", "London, UK", "Nijmegen, The Netherlands", 
"Vienna, Austria", "NYC, USA", "Paris, France", "Namur, Belgique", 
"Innsbruck, Austria", "Strasbourg, France", "Dallas, USA", "Strasbourg, France", 
"Dallas, USA", "Brussels, Belgium", "Chelmsford, UK", "Salzburg, Austria", 
"Stuttgart, Germany", "chicago USA", "Toronto Canada", "Dortmund, Germany", 
"San Francisco USA", "pittsford, NY, USA", "innsbruck, austria", 
"dallas, USA", "Strasbourg, France", "NYC, USA", "Ljubljana, Slovenia", 
"Chelmsford, UK", "Dallas, USA"), type = c("TUG", "PAP", "PAP", 
"TUG", "PAP", "PAP", "PAP", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "PAP", 
"TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "TUG", 
"TUG", "TUG", "TUG", "PAP", "TUG", "TUG", "PAP"), `no. of flaps` = c(54, 
22, 40, 37, 164, 30, 17, 154, 44, 24, 14, 101, 49, 14, 26, 58, 
33, 16, 32, 32, 27, 12, 31, 16, 27, 8, 19, 265), lon = c(-0.1277583, 
-0.1277583, 5.8428281, 16.3738189, -74.0059728, 2.3522219, 4.8719854, 
11.4041024, 7.7521113, -96.7969879, 7.7521113, -96.7969879, 4.3517103, 
0.4685497, 13.05501, 9.1829321, -87.6297982, -79.3831843, 7.4652981, 
-122.4194155, -77.5275463, 11.4041024, -96.7969879, 7.7521113, 
-74.0059728, 14.5057515, 0.4685497, -96.7969879), lat = c(51.5073509, 
51.5073509, 51.8448837, 48.2081743, 40.7127753, 48.856614, 50.4673883, 
47.2692124, 48.5734053, 32.7766642, 48.5734053, 32.7766642, 50.8503396, 
51.7355868, 47.80949, 48.7758459, 41.8781136, 43.653226, 51.5135872, 
37.7749295, 43.0789942, 47.2692124, 32.7766642, 48.5734053, 40.7127753, 
46.0569465, 51.7355868, 32.7766642)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -28L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Address = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), `no. of flaps` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), lon = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), lat = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

And I've used it to create two different maps, one of Europe, one of North America:

```
Map <- map_data("world")


NorthAmerica<-LocationData%>%filter(str_detect(Address, "USA|Canada"))%>%separate(Address, into = c("City","Country"), sep = ",")%>%mutate(City= str_remove_all(City, "USA| Canada"))
  SingleCityNorthAmerica<-NorthAmerica%>%group_by(City)%>%summarise(lon=mean(lon),lat=mean(lat))%>%mutate(City=str_to_title(City))
  
  
  
  Map%>%ggplot( aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill="lightgray", colour="white") +
  coord_quickmap(xlim = c(-130,-60), ylim = c(25,58)) +
  geom_point(data=NorthAmerica, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=`no. of flaps`, color=type, alpha=0.5), inherit.aes = FALSE)+labs(title="Research Location",  subtitle = "North America", size="Number of Flaps", y="Latitude", x="Longitude", color="Type")+geom_text_repel(data = SingleCityNorthAmerica, aes(label=City,x = lon, y = lat), inherit.aes = FALSE)+guides(alpha=FALSE)+ scale_size(range = c(0, 10))

Europe<-LocationData%>%filter(!str_detect(Address, "USA|Canada"))%>%separate(Address, into = c("City","Country"), sep = ",")%>%mutate(City= str_remove_all(City, "USA| Canada"))
  SingleCityEurope<-Europe%>%group_by(City)%>%summarise(lon=mean(lon),lat=mean(lat))%>%mutate(City=str_to_title(City))
  
  
  
  Map%>%ggplot( aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(fill="lightgray", colour="white") +
  coord_quickmap(xlim = c(-20,25), ylim = c(25,58)) +
  geom_point(data=Europe, aes(x=lon, y=lat, size=`no. of flaps`, color=type, alpha=0.5), inherit.aes = FALSE)+labs(title="Research Location", subtitle = "Europe",size="Number of Flaps", y="Latitude", x="Longitude", color="Type")+geom_text_repel(data = SingleCityEurope, aes(label=City,x = lon, y = lat), inherit.aes = FALSE)+guides(alpha=FALSE)+ scale_size(range = c(0, 10))
```

What I'd like to do is make those two facets of the same plot, primarily so that I can be assured the scale on the size of the points is the same for each, also it'll save some space in the manuscript rather than having two figures.  Can facets "zoom" to different locations?  Does that make sense?

Comment: Could your problem be solved using `gridExtra` (or `layout()`, for that matter) instead of 'facets'? You could just arrange them side by side and just remove the legend of one of the plots or so.

Comment: @Ben Possibly.  Would that solve the question of making the scale the same?  I.e. dots in one map that represent "150" for instance would be the same size as "150" dots on the other map? Or I suppose I could try to fix that ahead of time worst case.   I'll leave the question for now as I'm curious about whether facet can work